# Python consider punctuation in pig latin program

Tags: python, string

I am trying to build a English to Pig Latin conversion program in python. My program successfully converts all English words to Pig Latin words. But I don't understand how to place punctuation marks to be at the same place in Pig Latin sentence as it is in the original English sentence. I converted the punctuation marks coming either in last or first position of words but I am not able to convert punctuations coming in between of word like apostrophe s('s) or 2 punctuation marks coming together like question mark(?) with sentence closing single/double quote('/"), etc. Here is my code:

```
import string
import random
def take_input(sentence):
    prefix=[]
    stem=[]
    word_ans=[]
    punc=[]
    sent_ans=[]
    for word in sentence.split():
        word=list(word)
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i] in ('A','E','I','O','U','Y','a','e','i','o','u','y'):
                stem=word[i:]
                break
            else:
                prefix.append(word[i])
        for x in stem:
            word_ans.append(x)
        for x in prefix:
            word_ans.append(x)
        word_ans.append('a')
        word_ans.append('y')
        if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
            word_ans.remove(word[-1])
            word_ans.append(word[-1])
        if word[0] in string.punctuation:
            word_ans.remove(word[0])
            word_ans[1:]=word_ans
            word_ans[0]=word[0]
        for i in word_ans:
            sent_ans.append(i)
        sent_ans.append(' ')
        del prefix[:]
        del stem[:]
        del word_ans[:]
    sent_answer=''.join(sent_ans)
    return sent_answer
Answer=take_input("'Hi, How are you?'")
print Answer
```

Desired Output:'iHay, owHay areay youay?'

Current Output:i'Hay, owHay areay you?ay'

Comment: Try chopping off non-alpha characters at the beginning and end of the original string before you start, then slap em back on when you're all done pig-latinizing.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

Comment: Have you decided what to do with "aren't" and other words with internal punctuation (is "hello.c" one word?)

Comment: @cphlewis yes thats what, my words having internal punctuation line don't , john's, etc are not getting converted properly

Comment: What's "proper" for those words? Decide what should happen and write the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use regular expressions:

```
import re
text = 'Hi, how are you? I am fine.'
tokens = re.split("(\W)", text)
pig_tokens = map(lambda t: t if not re.search('\w', t) else t[-1].upper() + t[:-1].lower() + 'ay', tokens)
print ''.join(pig_tokens) # Ihay, Whoay Earay Uyoay? Iay Maay Efinay.
```

Comment: This too is not working with sentence having words with apostrophe s or words like don't